# Why can't the GPUs communicate in a multi-GPU server?

Tags: linux, dell-poweredge, bios, hpc, gpu

This is a Dell PowerEdge r750xa server with 4 Nvidia A40 GPUs, intended for AI applications. While the GPUs work well individually, multi-GPU training jobs or indeed any multi-GPU computational workload fails where at least 2 GPUs have to exchange information, including the [simpleIPC](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master/Samples/simpleIPC) and the [conjugateGradientMultiDeviceCG](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master/Samples/conjugateGradientMultiDeviceCG) CUDA samples (the first one shows mismatching results, the second just hangs).

I have seen online discussions ([1](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/repeatable-system-freezes-under-gpu-load-with-ubuntu-19-04-2x2080ti/74060), [2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Detectron/issues/219), [3](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/multi-gpu-training-hangs/82002)), claiming that something called the IOMMU must be turned off. I tried setting the `iommu=off` and `intel_iommu=off` Linux kernel flags but it didn't help. I checked the BIOS settings, but there is no option to turn IOMMU off in the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no explicit "IOMMU off" setting in this BIOS flavour, the problem is still with the BIOS configuration.

In the BIOS, go to **"Integrated Devices"** and change the **"Memory Mapped I/O Base"** setting from the default "56TB" to **"12TB"**. This will solve the issue. There is no need to add any extra kernel parameters.